# How do I get a certain number of objects from one arrayList in one class to an arraylist in another class?

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to make a card game and it has classes of Game, Card, Player, Deck and hand. I want it to simulate real life where you draw 5 cards from a deck to your hand

I have my class Player adding all the cards to an Deck array called cards.
Like this:

```
public Player(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.deck = new Deck();                                 
        this.deck.addCard(new Card("c1",20, "fire"));       
        this.deck.addCard(new Card("c2",30, "fire"));       
        this.deck.addCard(new Card("c3",10,"water")); //etc list goes on
```

which passes it to my class Deck:

```
public class Deck {
    private List<Card> cards;

    public Deck() {
        this.cards = new ArrayList<>(); 
    }

    public void addCard(Card card) {
        this.cards.add(card);           
    }
```

I created a hand arraylist in class Hand called hand:

```
public class Hand {
       Deck deck;

       private List<Card> hand;

       public Hand() {
            this.hand = new ArrayList<>();
        }
```

How do I add 5 random card objects from my deck arraylist to my hand arrayList?

Comment: "_How do I add 5 random card objects from my deck arraylist to my hand arrayList?_" This is multiple steps. Which one do you have difficulty with? Taking an object from a list? Adding an object to a list? Generating a random number to get an element from a list?

Comment: Hint: to randomize a `List`, shuffle it: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle-java.util.List-

Comment: I would like to work out how to transfer cards from my Deck arraylist and transfer 5 cards to it is probably my important bit.

Comment: Did you read the API for `List`?  What methods look promising?  Show us what you have tried. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html

Comment: I tried the get method just to try to pass a card from the arraylist Deck cards = card.get(0); hand.add(card); something like this so I probably want to place some rand index into the 0 for hand?

Comment: See my comment above for "rand index" (hint: after a shuffle you don't need to do that.)  So you've got 75% of the puzzle which you should add to your code (meaning add the code in your comment above to your question).  There's one missing piece: what happens to the original deck after a card is added to a player's hand?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to make Deck smart enough to withdraw cards randomly and with demanded amount. Deck code should be like this:

```
public class Deck {
    private List<Card> cards;

    public Deck() {
        this.cards = new ArrayList<>(); 
    }

    public void addCard(Card card) {
        this.cards.add(card);           
    }

    public List<Card> getCards(final int amount) {
        ArrayList<Card> result = new ArrayList<>();
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
            int randomIndex = random.nextInt(cards.size()); 
            result.add(cards.remove(randomIndex));
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

In the second step make Hand access to Deck, for this task Deck should be inside of the Hand class like this:

```
public class Hand {
       private final Deck deck;
       private final int cardsAmount;
       private List<Card> cardsInHand;

       public Hand(Deck deck, int cardsAmount) {
            this.deck = deck;
            this.cardsAmount = cardsAmount;
       }

       public List<Card> cards() {
           if(cardsInHand == null) cardsInHand = deck.getCards(cardsAmount);
           return cards;
       }

}
```

In real life player knows how many cards he should get from deck according to game rules, so we pass amount of cards to Hand constructor. When hand is empty we should get cards from deck, when hand is full simple return presented cards.